# How to find extrema per cell in 3 dimensional array with Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I have recently written a script to convert BGR arrays of [0, 1] floats to HSL and back. I posted it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286798/numpy-script-to-convert-bgr-to-hsl-and-back). There is currently one answer but it doesn't improve performance.

I have benchmarked my code against `cv2.cvtColor` and found my code to be inefficient, so I want to compile the code with Numba to make it run faster.

I have tried to wrapping every function with `@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)`, and this doesn't work.

So I have tested every NumPy syntax and NumPy functions I have used individually, and found two functions that don't work with Numba.

I need to find the maximum channel of each pixel (`np.max(img, axis=-1)`) and minimum channel of each pixel (`np.max(img, axis=-1)`), and the `axis` argument doesn't work with Numba.

I have tried to Google search this but the only thing even remotely relevant I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304720/workaround-for-numpy-np-all-axis-argument-compatibility-with-numba), but it only implements `np.any` and `np.all`, and only works for two dimensional arrays whereas here the arrays are three-dimensional.

I can write a for loop based solution but I won't write it, because it is bound to be inefficient and against the purpose of using NumPy and Numba in the first place.

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def max_per_cell(arr):
    return np.max(arr, axis=-1)

@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def min_per_cell(arr):
    return np.min(arr, axis=-1)

img = np.random.random((3, 4, 3))
max_per_cell(img)
min_per_cell(img)
```

Exception:

```
In [2]: max_per_cell(img)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 max_per_cell(img)

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function amax at 0x0000014E306D3370>) found for signature:

 >>> amax(array(float64, 3d, C), axis=Literal[int](-1))

There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'npy_max': File: numba\np\arraymath.py: Line 541.
    With argument(s): '(array(float64, 3d, C), axis=int64)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
  raised from C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\templates.py:784

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function amax at 0x0000014E306D3370>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-1-b3894b8b12b8> (10)


File "<ipython-input-1-b3894b8b12b8>", line 10:
def max_per_cell(arr):
    return np.max(arr, axis=-1)
    ^
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Well, as the link you provided mention : this is not yet supported by Numba. If you wish to add the support in Numba that would be great since many Numba users would like such a feature. As of now, the solution is provided by the link you mention. You just need to add a loop for the 3D case and use another function in the loop body... If this post is a request for asking new features not yet supported in Numba then GitLab issues are made for that.

Comment: *"it is bound to be inefficient"* This statement is actually wrong. Numba generally uses basic loops internally. This is also why some Numpy function using Numba are slower than Numpy alone (`np.where` for example). Numpy developers sometimes use (SIMD) intrinsics while Numba does not. While Numba developers could do that, this is currently a pain to do (so far).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to find both the minimum and maximum of an BGR array per cell in Numba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028447/fastest-way-to-find-both-the-minimum-and-maximum-of-an-bgr-array-per-cell-in-num)

Comment: @JérômeRichard numpy routines are commonly generic/flexible enough, hence have to do more work, such that a numba-optimized loop will run faster.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Technically, this is not so true (on large arrays). Numpy actually uses specialized kernels to optimize specific cases in many functions. This is done intensively in `np.where` but also in `np.einsum` or even `np.sum`. That being said, this introduces a significant maintainability costs (and development effort). This is the key point explaining why it is not systematically done. Numba kernels tends to be inherently specialized (not always though) so the JIT can do the job that the Numpy team should do manually resulting in faster computation (when it is properly vectorized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reasonably straightforward to implement this without `np.max()`, using loops instead:

```
@nb.njit()
def max_per_cell_nb(arr):
    ret = np.empty(arr.shape[:-1], dtype=arr.dtype)
    n, m = ret.shape
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            max_ = arr[i, j, 0]
            max_ = max(max_, arr[i, j, 1])
            max_ = max(max_, arr[i, j, 2])
            ret[i, j] = max_
    return ret
```

Benchmarking it, it turns out to be about 16x faster than `np.max(arr, axis=-1)`.

```
%timeit max_per_cell_nb(img)
4.88 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit max_per_cell(img)
81 ms ± 654 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

While benchmarking this, I made the following assumptions:

- The image is 1920x1080x3. (In other words, it's a big image.)
- The image array is in C order rather than Fortran order. If it's in Fortran order, the speed of my method drops to 7ms, and the speed of `np.max()` gets faster and only takes 15 ms. See [Check if numpy array is contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304154/check-if-numpy-array-is-contiguous) for how to tell if your array is in C or Fortran order. Your example of `np.random.random((3, 4, 3))` is C contiguous.
- I'm comparing this function to `np.max(arr, axis=-1)` with Numba JIT turned off, because it can't really optimize single calls to NumPy functions.

Comment: Good. Note that the speed up is mainly due to the fact the the last dimension is small and Numpy is very inefficient in that case (due to an internal generic iterator meant to support many features like broadcasting). The problem is that the input layout is inefficient in the first place. 1920x1080x3 should be replaced by the 3x1920x1080 layout (like OpenCV does AFAIK). With the later, compilers (and so Numpy and Numba) can generate a significantly faster code using SIMD instructions (30~60x times faster when the code is not memory bound).

Comment: no, opencv does not do CWH in most of the library. nobody does WH. opencv has support for NCHW in the DNN module only. nothing here is related to DNNs. 3-channel HWC is hard to optimize *perfectly* though it's possible. CPU cache helps a lot, and you need not use the result of an entire SIMD computation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Numba appears to be smart enough to vectorize the channel-last approach. At least, it is making use of the VMAXSS instruction. I am not sure how efficiently it is using the instruction. Rewriting this into a channel-first array, it seems to be about 4% slower. Could be a memory bandwidth issue. It is a very simple calculation, after all.

Comment: @NickODell VMAXSS is a *scalar* single-precision max instruction. This is not a *packed* instruction operating on multiple values at the same time (despite the presence of the VEX prefix and the fact that the instruction is a part of the AVX instruction set). Thus, this is not really a SIMD instruction. The SIMD counterpart is VMAXPS.

Comment: @NickODell The code is certainly not memory-bound either (possibly page-fault-bound though). Indeed, 1 array of size 1920x1080x3 is read and one of the size 1920x1080 is written. This means a throughput of `(3+2)*4*1920*1024/1024**3/4.88e-3 ~= 7.5 GiB/s`. This is very small and most modern PC should at least reach >15 GiB/s. Note the `3+2` (instead of `3+1`) is due to cache-lines write-allocates on x86-64 CPUs.

Comment: @NickODell I checked that on my machine. The RAM throughput while running the code is "only" 17 GiB/s (40% of the max). There is not much page faults (not the bottleneck). The computation is sequential and scalar. The throughput very closely matches with 1 store/cycle (limit of my CPU) which is 16.8 GiB/s. Thus, I conclude the scalar implementation is the bottleneck. However, an SIMD implementation will quickly be memory bound on PCs, unless it operated on 8-bit RGB integers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Sounds like you could still get 2x the performance, though, even if it were bandwidth capped. Do you want to take a shot at writing a SIMD implementation? I couldn't get a CWH implementation to run any faster. Would be curious to see your approach.

Comment: @NickODell Actually, Numba simply fail to generate SIMD instructions in most cases. It looks like this is due to the auto-vectorizer in LLVM. This is pretty common in compilers unfortunately (and also why writing C code with intrinsics turns out to be often faster). I succeed to generate faster implementations but it is hard both not to create temporary arrays AND a function using SIMD instructions. I think I finally succeed using a quite convoluted way in Numba.

Comment: I added an answer to share an implementation using SIMD instructions. The provided implementation is rather simple.

Answer (score 2):

### CHW implementation

Following the comments of the answer of @NickODell, here is a faster **SIMD-friendly solution** when the image use a *CWH layout* (as requested by @NickODell):

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize('(float32, float32, float32)')
def vec_max(a, b, c):
    return max(a, b, c)

@nb.njit('(float32[:,:,::1], float32[:,::1])')
def max_per_cell_chw_nb_faster(a, b):
    vec_max(a[0], a[1], a[2], b)

# Benchmark

img1 = np.random.rand(1920, 1080, 3).astype(np.float32)
img2 = np.random.rand(3, 1920, 1080).astype(np.float32)
out = np.empty((1920, 1080), dtype=np.float32)

%timeit out = max_per_cell_nb(img1)
%timeit max_per_cell_chw_nb_faster(img2, out)
```

Here is the result on my machine (i5-9600KF + 40 GiB/s RAM on Windows):

```
3 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.08 ms ± 6.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This means this implementation is **3 times faster** on 32-bit floats. The former version is scalar, while the later use **SIMD instructions**. The former is also slowed down by **page-faults** while the later does not. The SIMD version could be even faster if it would not be **memory-bound**. The smaller the data-type the faster the SIMD implementation. With 8-bit unsigned integer, the SIMD version is about **9 times faster** and *still memory-bound*:

```
1.83 ms ± 9.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
210 µs ± 3.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

### HWC implementation

Note that the version of @NickODell can be generated by simply replacing the one-line content of `max_per_cell_nb_faster` by the following so to support HWC images:

```py
@nb.njit('(float32[:,:,::1], float32[:,::1])')
def max_per_cell_hwc_nb_faster(a, b):
    vec_max(a[:,:,0], a[:,:,1], a[:,:,2], b)
```

However, this version is a bit slower than the solution of @NickODell (despite simpler) since it does not uses SIMD instructions internally:

```
3.35 ms ± 50.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

In fact, AFAIK, the LLVM optimizer is not yet able to vectorize this access-pattern (because this is pretty hard, and it is generally less efficient than using CWH even when done manually and carefully).