# subtracting a numpy array by a list is slow

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array of shape `4000x4000x3`, which is an image with 3 channels, subtract each channel by some values. I can do it as following:

**Implementation 1**

```
values = [0.43, 0.44, 0.45]
image -= values
```

Or,

**Implementation 2**

```
values = [0.43, 0.44, 0.45]
for i in range(3):
    image[...,i] -= values[i]
```

Surprisingly, the later solution is 20x faster than the former when performing on that large image shape, but I don't clearly know why. Could you please explain what helps the second implementation faster? Thanks.

Simple script for confirmation:

```
import time
import numpy as np

image = np.random.rand(4000, 4000, 3).astype("float32")
values = [0.43, 0.44, 0.45]

st = time.time()
for i in range(3):
    image[..., i] -= values[i]
et = time.time()
print("Implementation 2", et - st)

st = time.time()
image -= values
et = time.time()
print("Implementation 1", et - st)
```

**Output**

```
Implementation 2 0.030953645706176758 
Implementation 1 0.8593623638153076
```

Comment: How did you time this? Getting `138 ms ± 4.41 ms` for the vectorial approach and `232 ms ± 16.1 ms` for the loop.

Comment: `103 ms ± 6.8 ms` vs `95.3 ms ± 7.35 ms` actually when using `-=` (my first test was with a copy), but nowhere near 20x faster. Also tested with a larger number for the last dimension. I believe this should be the same timing since in one case you have an internal conversion to array and the other a loop.

Comment: @mozway Thread updated, check attached script, thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce a difference and indeed get a worse timing with numpy (5x). Interestingly I had tested with `np.zeros` without difference.

Comment: @mozway, changed to `np.zeros((4000, 4000, 3)).astype("float32")` but got the same result (subtracting using for loop is still 20x faster)

Comment: I get only a small difference with `numpy.zeros` and the default dtype (`float64`) (measured with `%%timeit`)

Comment: @mozway I believe Numpy changed the way `-=` works. I could not find the link though, but recall something like that. ie it no longer does the in place as we know it. it changed to match the results of `=`. This was due to the way the operator `-=` misbehaved when used with numpy arrays. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047111/vs-operators-with-numpy/9047371#9047371 for example on how `-=` used to behave  previously. After the update `image -= values` should have same time as `image = image - values`. This is not inplace replacement. Thus I believe higher time compared to for loop

Comment: The whole-array approach does better if `values` is an array.  It saves the list to array conversion set.  I get some `timing` differences, but on the order of 5%, nothing like 20x.  And that's for a variety of sizes, and `+=` as well.

Comment: @hpaulj `values` is automatically converted to an array by Numpy anyway and this operation is very cheap here because `len(values) = 3`. It takes less than 0.003 ms on my machine, that is <0.01% of the time. All native Numpy functions always operate on arrays (though items can be CPython objects for non-native-typed arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: the performance issue is caused by multiple factors :

- Numpy iterators introduce a big overhead on small broadcasted arrays
- `values` is implicitly converted to a `np.float64` array causing a slow `np.float64`-based subtraction
- the memory layout is sub-optimal in all implementations

---

### Numpy internal iterators

One issue comes from the Numpy implementation. Numpy uses an inefficient code for handling small array that are *broadcasted*. This is due to an internal concept called **Numpy iterators which introduce a significant overhead when arrays are small** because of the number of repeated iteration on the same small array. This concept is necessary in Numpy to make the computing code more generic and to support many features, especially broadcasting.

On top of that, Numpy cannot benefit from using SIMD instructions in this case because the array is too small to even fit in a SIMD register of mainstream CPUs.

A simple way to prove this hypothesis is to flatten the array and analyse the performance of subtracting arrays of different size containing the same repeated values:

```py
view = image.reshape(-1, 3)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 1)

view = image.reshape(-1, 6)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 2)

view = image.reshape(-1, 12)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 4)

view = image.reshape(-1, 24)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 8)

view = image.reshape(-1, 384)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 128)

view = image.reshape(-1, 3*4000)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 4000)

# Pathological case : huge generated array
view = image.reshape(-1, 3*4000*1000)
%time view -= np.tile(values, 4000*1000)
```

Here are results on my machine with an Intel Xeon W-2255 CPU using Numpy 1.20.3:

```
Implementation 2 0.06000018119812012
Implementation 1 0.1734762191772461
```

```
Wall time: 175 ms
Wall time: 137 ms
Wall time: 106 ms
Wall time: 95 ms
Wall time: 67 ms     <-----
Wall time: 69 ms
Wall time: 108 ms
```

One can see that the bigger the second array the better in the above benchmark. However, when the subtracted array is too big, it takes too much time to generate the repeated array using `np.tile`. Indeed, the array is so big it does not fit in the (fast) caches of the CPU but the (slow) DRAM. Since the operation is rather *memory bound*, it can be more than twice slower.

One can see that the fastest timing of the flatten operation is close to "Implementation 2". It is a bit slower (probably still certainly due to Numpy internal iterators).

---

### Datatypes and implicit conversions

Another big issue is that `values` is a list of `float` objects. It is **implicitly converted to a 1D array of `np.float64` values while `image` is of type `np.float32`**. Due to the **type promotion** rules in Numpy, the operations is done using the `np.float64` type which is significantly slower and not needed here anyway.

We can fix that by **creating the Numpy array explicitly with the right data-type** : `values = np.array(values, dtype=np.float32)`. Here are the results of the same (above) benchmark code but now using a `np.float32` array:

```py
Wall time: 75 ms
Wall time: 46 ms
Wall time: 39 ms
Wall time: 31 ms
Wall time: 23 ms
Wall time: 18 ms     <-----
```

We can see that using only `np.float32`-based operations is much faster.

---

### More explanations

> Could you please explain what helps the second implementation faster?

The second implementation operate on `np.float32` values and do not suffer from the iterator overhead since there is no broadcasting done internally. This is because the right-hand-side is a unique `float` scalar. Numpy directly converts the value to a `np.float32` iternally in this case for sake of performance since the left-hand-side is a `np.float32` array. You can check that by manually converting the value to `np.float32`. Note that Numpy apparently convert the value to a `np.float32` one even when it is a `np.float64` one internally.

However, this implementation is not efficient because it walks through the whole array `image` 3 times (so the whole array needs to be read and written back from/to the DRAM 3 times).

---

### Final optimized code

Put it shortly, you can write:

```py
st = time.time()
image -= np.tile(np.array(values, dtype=np.float32), image.shape[1]).reshape(-1, 3)
et = time.time()
print("Implementation 3", et - st)  # 0.018 seconds
```

---

### Notes on memory layouts

While repeating `values` `image.shape[1]` times is guaranteed to work and it should be generally quite fast, the best solution is to **avoid using the layout `height x width x components`** which tends to be inefficient (fundamentally not SIMD friendly), especially with Numpy. Instead, it is better to **use the layout `component x height x width`** (or even possibly `height x component x width` which tends to be a good tread-off of the two). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024623/how-to-find-extrema-per-cell-in-3-dimensional-array-with-numba/77047550#77047550) for example. Note that, for the same reason, it is much better to use a `(2,N)`-shaped array than the common `(N,2)` one.

Comment: The "implemtation 3" again performs 3X faster than the for loop version. Thanks.